# AngularJs download arquivo de ASP.MVC5 passando parametros

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, angularjs, download, blob

**Situação:**
Tenho uma API em ASP MVC5 que gera um excel.xlsx e retorna ele em um FileContentResult. Tudo em memoria, pois não posso salvar o arquivo no disco do servidor.Funciona ok se acesso diretamente a url.

Tenho uma aplicação AngularJS que precisa passar um Json enorme para a API e receber o arquivo .xlsx gerado.

Estou tentando o seguinte:

**Controler:**

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> Excel([FromBody]GetGeneralFilterVM operationHistoryFilter = null)
    {
        var ListaOperazioni = await GetListaOperazioniData(operationHistoryFilter);
        var Totals = await GetExcelTotalsData(operationHistoryFilter);

        var excelExport = new ExcelExportEntity(new object[]
            {
                ListaOperazioni,
                Totals,
            });
        var preFile = excelExport.DoExcel();
        var arraybits = preFile;
        var file = File(arraybits, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "OperationHistory.xlsx");

        return file;
    }
```

**Angular:**

```
$scope.exportExcel = () => {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: appPath + "controller/Excel",
        data: filter, 
        success: function (response) {
            var file = new Blob([response], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
                var fileName = "excelFeliz.xlsx";
                saveAs(file, fileName);
            },
            error: function (ajaxContext) {
                alert('Export error: ' + ajaxContext.responseText);
            }
        });
}
```

**Resultado:** Assim chega até a fazer o download de um arquivo, porém ao tentar abrir ele está corrompido.

Minha insistência no AJAX é por culpa do GetGeneralFilterVM que estou recebendo na controller, ele contem sub-objetos com muitas propriedades seria complicadissimo colocar isso como parametros na url.

Também não tenho como gerar e retornar uma url para download, porque não tenho como salvar o arquivo no disco do servidor.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Eia Alam - quão 'enorme' é este arquivo? Se você está fazendo tudo em memória você está provavelmente limitado a uma quota de uso.

Comment: O excel em si não é tão grande, fica com cerca de 10 ou 15KB. Por que a pergunta?

Comment: @OnoSendai na verdade o que eu falei que é "enorme" é o Json com os parâmetros para filtrar os dados. Ele não é grande em peso, mas em número de campos. O GetGeneralFilterVM (esqueça esse get na frente, o nome ta ruim) é uma viewmodel com 5 objetos e cada objeto com suas propriedades... somadas são mais de 30 e algumas são listas

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito pesquisar encontrei uma maneira, esta sim funciona 100%. Ao invés de usar AJAX, que parece ter problemas com blob, usei uma chamada XMLHttpRequest.
Obs.: A controller não foi alterada.

```
getExportExcel: function (filter) {

        var json_upload = "operationHistoryFilter=" + JSON.stringify(filter);
        var url = appPath + "OperationHistoryReport/ExcelGeneral";
        var fileName = "excel.xlsx"
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.responseType = 'blob';

        request.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var blob = this.response;
                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                }
                else {
                    var downloadLink = window.document.createElement('a');
                    var contentTypeHeader = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { type: contentTypeHeader }));
                    downloadLink.download = fileName;
                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                    downloadLink.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
                }
            }
        };
        request.send(JSON.stringify(filter));
}
```